# Splunk: Configure inputs.conf to parse only JSON files

Tags: splunk

How do I setup inputs.conf in splunk to parse only JSON files found on multiple directories? I could define a single sourcetype (KV_MODE=json) in props.conf but not sure about the code in inputs.conf.

Currently, I have the file with multiple stanzas that would each specify the application log path having json files. Each stanza has a sourcetype defined in props.conf to point to json KV_mode. I would like to minimize the steps and consolidate into a single stanza if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Each `monitor` stanza in Splunk monitors a single file path, although that path can contain wildcards.  You could do something like `[monitor:///.../*.json]` to monitor any file anywhere with a json extension, but that would consume a crazy amount of resources.

You're better off with a separate stanza for each directory that contains JSON data.  Maybe you can use wildcards to condense to a few entries.

All of them, however, can use the same sourcetype so there's no need to touch props.conf to monitor a new file path.